# Type declaration based on type parameters in inner classes

Tags: java, generics, inner-classes

Does Java shadow type parameters? I am finding it hard to test for myself because Java generics do not get reified at run time.

For example, given this code:

```
public class NestedGeneric<T> {
    private InnerGeneric<T> innerGenericInstance;

    private static class InnerGeneric<T> {
        public T innerGenericField;
    }

    NestedGeneric() {
    innerGenericInstance = new InnerGeneric<T>();
    }
}
```

Both the below statements compile fine:

```
NestedGeneric<Integer> test1 = new NestedGeneric<Integer>();
NestedGeneric.InnerGeneric<String> test2  = new NestedGeneric.InnerGeneric<String>();
```

When the `NestedGeneric` is passed a type parameter and its constructor called, what is `T`? Is it always going to be the same as the type parameter passed to `nestedGeneric`?

In other words, can an outer classes type parameters be passed to an inner classes generic type declarations?

Comment: Yes it can, but not mandatory. You could also make the inner class another object, but you want to change the T to a `U` in the nested class creation.

Comment: Type parameters seem to be shadowed http://ideone.com/8DihKQ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In other words, I suppose the question is, can an outer classes type
>   parameters be passed to an inner classes generic type declarations?

No. There is no relationship (like inheritance or as a field) between the outer and the inner **static** class. You can create an object of the inner static class without any dependency on the outer class like in your example:

```
NestedGeneric.InnerGeneric<String> test2  = new NestedGeneric.InnerGeneric<String>();
```

However when you use **an instance** of the inner class as a field the generic type is derived from the outer class:

```
private InnerGeneric<T> innerGenericInstance;

innerGenericInstance = new InnerGeneric<T>();
```

A third variation would be to define the **inner class as a field (non-static)**:

```
private class InnerGeneric<T> {
    public T innerGenericField;
}
```

which will now get the type from the outer class since its a member variable.

As pointed out in the comment defining both inner static & outer class with the type  will just confuse the reader (and yourself at a later point in time). It should be declared with a different generic like

```
public class NestedGeneric<T> {
    private InnerGeneric<T> innerGenericInstance;

    private static class InnerGeneric<U> {
        private U innerGenericField;
    }

    NestedGeneric() {
        innerGenericInstance = new InnerGeneric<T>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is not a shadowing. There is only one type parameter int your code, the `T` parameter. So inner and outer `T` are the same type parameters.

You can of course have more type parameters.

```
public class NestedGeneric<OUTER_TYPE> {

  private static class InnerGeneric<INNER_TYPE> {
    public INNER_TYPE innerGenericField;
  }

  public NestedGeneric() {
    InnerGeneric<OUTER_TYPE> innerGenericInstance = new InnerGeneric<OUTER_TYPE>();

   InnerGeneric<String> secondInnerGenerics = new InnerGeneric<String>();
  } 
}
```

The `INNER_TYPE` and the `OUTER_TYPE` are two different type parameters. Line `InnerGeneric<OUTER_TYPE>  innerGenericInstance = new InnerGeneric<OUTER_TYPE>();` will say thad `innerGenericInstance` is parametrized by the same type as `OUTER_TYPE` is. But they do not have to be the same. As it is in the case of `secondInnerGenerics` variable.

Comment: So it's only the point of declaration that matters? Even if they COULD be named differently, I want to understand the behaviour when they are named the same. If the inner classes type parameters carry the same name as the outer class, are they still completely independent?

Comment: In the OP's code, there are actually two type parameters: one for NestedGeneric and one for InnerGeneric. The fact that they are both called 'T' is confusing. The class definition @plastique gives uses different names for the type parameters, which makes it more obvious that they're different parameters but the definition is functionally identical.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but not with the static modifier:

```
public class NestedGeneric<T> {
    private InnerGeneric<T> innerGenericInstance;

    private class InnerGeneric<T> {
        private T innerGenericField;

        public InnerGeneric(T innerGenericField){
           this.innerGenericField = innerGenericField;
        }

        public T getInnerGenericField(){
           return this.innerGenericField;
        }
    }

    NestedGeneric(T someGenericVariable) {
        innerGenericInstance = new InnerGeneric<T>(someGenericVariable);
        T innerGenericField = innerGenericInstance.innerGenericInstance();
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case the inner generic class is not static which is treated differently

Comment: The inner class is static, but the instance of the inner class is stored in a non-static member variable.